# How many lives an organ donor with brain death who is otherwise healthy can save on average?

Tags: surgery, donor

Considering all of the probabilities including the probability of the rejection of the transplants, how many lives could this donor save on average if we transplant his organs to other people who need them to survive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Organ donation and utilization in the USA](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15113353)

- States about 3.6 organs are gathered from every deceased donor

**[Organdonor.gov](http://www.organdonor.gov) says a organ donor can save up to 8 lives and [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/healthy-lifestyle/consumer-health/in-depth/organ-donation/art-20047529) says you can save or improve up to 50 lives. Some sites say you can save over 50 and even [a 100 though](http://www.americantransplantfoundation.org/about-transplant/facts-and-myths/).**

[liveonny.org](http://www.liveonny.org/mobile/)

> One organ donor can save up to eight lives. The same donor can also
>   save or improve the lives of up to 50 people by donating tissues and
>   eyes.

However, most deceased organ donors are brain dead about [5%](https://sciencelife.uchospitals.edu/2014/02/20/the-challenge-of-organ-donation-after-cardiac-death/) have experienced cardiac arrest though. This does not affect the amount of organs donated usually, both donors give around the same amount. As for possible rejection of organs any patient with a donated organ could do that, there are some people who may have greater risk, but usually everyone needs to take meds to be safe from this.

Survival rates:

- [Kidney](http://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/kidney-transplant/basics/results/prc-20014007):

> About 98 percent of people who receive a living-donor kidney
>   transplant live for at least one year after their transplant surgery.
>   About 90 percent live for at least five years. About 94 percent of
>   adults who receive a deceased-donor kidney transplant live for at
>   least one year after their transplant surgery. About 82 percent live
>   for at least five years.

- [Liver](http://www.uphs.upenn.edu/news/News_Releases/2014/07/goldberg/): 
  The 3 year survival rate was 78% and the 71% survival rate was for 5 years.
- list of survival up to 10 years. I would have added the list, but it's very big as it includes all [organs](http://www.srtr.org/annual_Reports/2011/113a_dh.aspx).

Comment: Nice answer. However I would also like to know about the average survival rate of the patients who receive the transplants if possible.

Comment: @didam I added the average for kidney and liver, and added a link for the rest.